# Open a model box when clicking header right button in react navigation stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

This is the app.js stack screen element

```
<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={
          { headerTitleStyle: { alignSelf: 'center' },
          headerRight: () => (
            <Button
              onPress={this.add}
              title="+"
              
            />
          )
        }
        }/>
```

Add function in app.js

```
add = async () => {
  this.setState({
    isVisible: true
  })
 }
```

Modal is present in homeScreen component

```
<Modal visible={this.state.isVisible} animationType={"slide"}
               onRequestClose={() => {this.props.isVisible=false} }>
```

Whenever the app is loading, it's going to the modal page. It's not rendering homescreen view.

Comment: maybe the state isVisible is set to true: i would recommend you read this section on react-navigation docu to open a fullscreen modal https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal/

Comment: @skorp I have gone through the above mentioned link. here it is mentioning how to open a modal throgh navigation. But for me I am not using navigation. I just want to open the modal on right button click of header

Comment: Got solution. added the button as using setparam in homescreem